# Add package to Web application without deploying whole project

Tags: jakarta-ee, model-view-controller, deployment, module

How to add & deploy a new package to an existing web application without actually deploying the whole project,

We have a product called click to call.This product has several different API's like 1. SMS to call  2. Miss-call-for -callback 3. Tweet to call etc.

Now all there project runs using a separate web application and uses Http Post and get method to communicate with each other. I need to merge all these separate application into one multi tire application so is it possible by any means or framework that every time i make any change i need to deply only that particular package and not the whole project

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

i'm unsure if i understand you right, but for the development purposes you can use JRebel. i don't know if there's any solution for the production environment, though it's still not good idea to redeploy something on production this way. imho.